# Some of database on my Maintenance Plan won't backup with an error "Operating System Error Code 3(The system cannot find the specified path)"

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plan

I have this job on maintenance plan of SQL Server 2014 SP3 which backup "All databases" to a shared file of another server, but one database failed due to an error shown on my screenshot below. Note that the rest are successful and they are just using the same path, all databases are simple except for model which is full.

[image: Error Logs]

[image: Screenshot of Maintenance Plan]

Comment: Is it the last database? If so, might be worth checking that the disk doesn't get full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think file path is the issue. As per the screenshot attached there is a space between your file path, which is causing error in creating as proper file path not found

[image]

Fix this and then try again, one more possibility is path not found please make sure that file path is correct. I did the same at my end and found same `error code 3` as mentioned in your screenshot.

[image]

Comment: DarkRob you are a damn good bro, my database has a white space. After removing it need to re-create the maintenenance job and now it's okay. Thank you bro.

Comment: update the question header with error code 3, so that other people will get the help for same.